# How to resolve IPs of AWS ELB in Openresty for every upstream

Tags: nginx, amazon-elb, openresty

The problem we're having is that openresty nginx only resolves the IP of AWS ELBs at startup and then caches the IP forever (until it reloads). Since the AWS loadbalancer IP can change anytime, I am looking for a solution that can resolve the ELB IPs for every time its being used in upstream.
Looking for something similar to upstream "resolve" option in nginx+, but in Openresty.
Or some other method to invalidate upstream DNS cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using a DNS server as your [`resolver`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#resolver) and a variable for the value of `proxy_pass`?

Look at the example below from this post ["Nginx with dynamic upstreams"](https://tenzer.dk/nginx-with-dynamic-upstreams/) by Jeppe Fihl-Pearson

```
resolver 172.16.0.23;
set $upstream_endpoint http://service-1234567890.us-east-1.elb.amazonaws.com;
location /foo/ {
    rewrite ^/foo/(.*) /$1 break;
    proxy_pass $upstream_endpoint;
}
```

Comment: ya this is good one also but it doesnt support variable e.g. 
`resolver $resolver_value;`

Comment: the targets are resolved dynamically by the resolver, why would a variable for the resolver be useful?

Comment: This solution cannot work with `proxy_protocol on;`

Answer (score 1):

There is [balancer module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-core/blob/master/lib/ngx/balancer.md) which you can use from within `balancer_by_lua_block` directive. You would be able to set any upstream IP.

> This Lua code execution context does not support yielding, so Lua APIs
>   that may yield (like cosockets and "light threads") are disabled in
>   this context. One can usually work around this limitation by doing
>   such operations in an earlier phase handler (like access_by_lua*) and
>   passing along the result into this context via the ngx.ctx table.

You may use [lua-resty-dns](https://github.com/openresty/lua-resty-dns) and resolve your ELB IP for every request (is it performant?!) in `access_by_lua_*`, save obtained IP(s) into ngx.ctx and use it within `balancer_by_lua_block`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It did help me in resolving the load balancer. But I ended up doing something very easy, which was to load dynamic module in openresty which did the same thing exactly

Answer (score 0):

Add this to the server directive

```
resolver local=on valid=5s;
```

You can then use the upstream block as usual.